# Phonegap, JQM and Android Slow Performance

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

What are your feelings and impressions about Phonegap (cordova) with jquery mobile on Android? I am developing a Phonegap app on that environment, however I see the display flickers in the page transitions and slow performance at general. Do you think I can do something to fix that?

Comment: If you simply copy/paste the title of your question into the search-box on Stack Overflow, you'll get a plethora of good information. This question gets asked a lot so there are a lot of answers but no silver bullets...

Comment: @Jasper I know that, and you are right. However, I tried a plethora of solutions too, but it did not solved my problem yet. I'd like to know if anybody else has the same issue so can give me a hand or some opinions too.

Comment: For better feedback, I would post what you have tried and what results you got from those tries. Once you have posted what you've tried, I'll try to fill-in what you haven't tried (along with the awesome devs here at SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this sometimes, but usually due to things that I'm doing wrong (i.e; not optimizing my code). Without any concrete code from your end, I would recommend the following tips.

1. Keep your "screens" simple. You're on a Mobile device so try to minimize the amount of elements you have on a single screen.
2. Have you tried just running your "site/app" in the Phone's browser? I know this is simplistic, but it's essentially how PhoneGap works anyways. See if you get the same issues.
3. What operations are you doing on the screen's startup? Again, keeping elements and effects to a minimum will help speed things up.

I wish I could be of more help, and don't take offense to this because it's not directed at you, but PhoneGap and using Web Techs is not an excuse for poor coding and optimization. I've built and used apps that were coded Natively and they still had performance issues.

So yeah, to concretely answer your question, I have experienced it, but it's not a PhoneGap thing (entirely anyways IMHO).

Comment: About your bullet point #2, if you test your "site/app" in the phone's browser and it performs about 10x better than it does on PhoneGap, what should you do then?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using this optimization tool to see if it will help you track down where the slow downs are happening and help you understand why http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312
Once you get the results of that you might be able to post more information, and people here might be able to provide more help.